# Bootstrap Glyphicons datetimepicker change icons

Tags: jquery, icons, glyphicons, bootstrap-datetimepicker, eonasdan-datetimepicker

I am using Bootstrap datetimepicker https://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/

As mentioned in the document I was successfully able to change the up, down arrows using below code.

```
$('#datetimepicker7').datetimepicker({
    sideBySide: true,
    icons: {
        up: "fa fa-chevron-circle-up",
        down: "fa fa-chevron-circle-down",
    }
});
```

May I know how to change the left, right icons of the calendar? For easy understanding I have highlighted the icons to be changes in below image.

[image: Bootstrap Glyphicons image]

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

In order to change left and right icons you just need to change in the below code:

```
icons: {
        time: 'glyphicon glyphicon-time',
        date: 'glyphicon glyphicon-calendar',
        up: 'glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-up',
        down: 'glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-down',
        //previous: 'glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left',
        previous: 'glyphicon glyphicon-backward',
        next: 'glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right',
        today: 'glyphicon glyphicon-screenshot',
        clear: 'glyphicon glyphicon-trash',
        close: 'glyphicon glyphicon-remove'
    },
```

By default the line which i have commented that icon is showing so if u need to change that icon you just simply have to set the path or any icon which you want to show.

You can refer below link:
 https://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/Options/

Answer (score 9):

You just have to insert `previous` and `next` keys in your `icons` object in the configuration as stated in the [docs](https://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/Options/#icons).

```js
$('#datetimepicker7').datetimepicker({
    sideBySide: true,
    icons: {
        up: "fa fa-chevron-circle-up",
        down: "fa fa-chevron-circle-down",
        next: 'fa fa-chevron-circle-right',
        previous: 'fa fa-chevron-circle-left'
    }
});
```

```html
<link href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datetimepicker/4.17.37/css/bootstrap-datetimepicker.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.6.3/css/font-awesome.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.13.0/moment.min.js"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datetimepicker/4.17.37/js/bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.js"></script>

<div class="form-group">
  <div class="input-group date" id="datetimepicker7">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" />
    <span class="input-group-addon"><span class="glyphicon-calendar glyphicon"></span></span>
  </div>
</div>
```