# Bootstrap datetimepicker icons not showing

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, icons, datetimepicker, bootstrap-datetimepicker

I am using bootstrap 3.x.x. and added datetimepicker 4.17 , datetimepicker is working fine but not showing the clock icon and nor the arrow icons.

https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datetimepicker/4.17.47/js/bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.js

https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datetimepicker/4.17.47/css/bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.css

[image]

i tried custom icons that worked also fine.

```
icons: {
    time: 'glyphicon glyphicon-time',
    date: 'glyphicon glyphicon-calendar',
    up: 'glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-up',
    down: 'glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-down',
    //previous: 'glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left',
    previous: 'glyphicon glyphicon-backward',
    next: 'glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right',
    today: 'glyphicon glyphicon-screenshot',
    clear: 'glyphicon glyphicon-trash',
    close: 'glyphicon glyphicon-remove'
}
```

[here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38519259/bootstrap-glyphicons-datetimepicker-change-icons)

But default icons are not showing up.
what i am missing please help!

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

Make sure you also load the glyphicon icon-font. 
That might be the reason why the icons aren't showing up.

Comment: when i do change the bootstrap version it works. that means there no issue with glyphicons. thanks

Comment: Not all versions of Bootstrap embed Glyphicon if I recall correctly. Try to link Glyphicon through a CDN and see if it fixes the problem.

Answer (score 1):

In bootstrap 4 I replaced those icons with font icons to make it work:

```
 $(".timepicker").datetimepicker({
            icons:
                {
                    up: 'fa fa-angle-up',
                    down: 'fa fa-angle-down'
                },
            format: 'LT'
        });
```