# How can I change Bootstrap Datepicker icons?

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-datepicker

I want to change **next** and **prev** arrows. But `innerHTML` is doesn't affect `<th class="next">>></th>`. What can I do?

```js
$(".datepicker").datepicker();
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.9.0/css/bootstrap-datepicker.min.css">

<input type="text" class="datepicker">

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.9.0/js/bootstrap-datepicker.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Bootstrap Glyphicons datetimepicker change icons](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38519259/bootstrap-glyphicons-datetimepicker-change-icons)

Comment: this is not duplicate. it datetimepicker. this datepicker. they are different.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change icon like this way :

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".datepicker").datepicker().on('show', function(e){
       $('.prev').text('<<<');
    $('.next').text(">>>");
    });
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.9.0/css/bootstrap-datepicker.min.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.9.0/js/bootstrap-datepicker.min.js"></script>

<input type="text" class="datepicker">
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is another idea with only CSS.

```js
$(".datepicker").datepicker();
```

```css
.table-condensed > thead > tr:nth-child(2) > .prev {
  font-size: 0;
  background: url("data:image/svg+xml,%0A%3Csvg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' width='24' height='24' viewBox='0 0 24 24' fill='none' stroke='currentColor' stroke-width='2' stroke-linecap='round' stroke-linejoin='round' %3E%3Cline x1='19' y1='12' x2='5' y2='12'%3E%3C/line%3E%3Cpolyline points='12 19 5 12 12 5'%3E%3C/polyline%3E%3C/svg%3E") 50% 50% / contain no-repeat;
}

.table-condensed > thead > tr:nth-child(2) > .next {
  font-size: 0;
  background: url("data:image/svg+xml, %3Csvg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' width='24' height='24' viewBox='0 0 24 24' fill='none' stroke='currentColor' stroke-width='2' stroke-linecap='round' stroke-linejoin='round' %3E%3Cline x1='5' y1='12' x2='19' y2='12'%3E%3C/line%3E%3Cpolyline points='12 5 19 12 12 19'%3E%3C/polyline%3E%3C/svg%3E") 50% 50% / contain no-repeat;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.9.0/css/bootstrap-datepicker.min.css">

<input type="text" class="datepicker">

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.9.0/js/bootstrap-datepicker.min.js"></script>
```

Change the color of icons by using `mask`: (You can already change the color of SVG by changing the fill or stroke color but let's say you're using a PNG instead of SVG)

```js
$(".datepicker").datepicker();
```

```css
.table-condensed > thead > tr:nth-child(2) > .prev {
  font-size: 0;
  --mask: url("data:image/svg+xml,%0A%3Csvg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' width='24' height='24' viewBox='0 0 24 24' fill='none' stroke='currentColor' stroke-width='2' stroke-linecap='round' stroke-linejoin='round' %3E%3Cline x1='19' y1='12' x2='5' y2='12'%3E%3C/line%3E%3Cpolyline points='12 19 5 12 12 5'%3E%3C/polyline%3E%3C/svg%3E") 50% 50% / contain no-repeat;
  -webkit-mask: var(--mask);
          mask: var(--mask);
   background: red;
}

.table-condensed > thead > tr:nth-child(2) > .next {
  font-size: 0;
  --mask: url("data:image/svg+xml, %3Csvg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' width='24' height='24' viewBox='0 0 24 24' fill='none' stroke='currentColor' stroke-width='2' stroke-linecap='round' stroke-linejoin='round' %3E%3Cline x1='5' y1='12' x2='19' y2='12'%3E%3C/line%3E%3Cpolyline points='12 5 19 12 12 19'%3E%3C/polyline%3E%3C/svg%3E") 50% 50% / contain no-repeat;
  -webkit-mask: var(--mask);
          mask: var(--mask);
   background: blue;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.9.0/css/bootstrap-datepicker.min.css">

<input type="text" class="datepicker">

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.9.0/js/bootstrap-datepicker.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to loop over prev and next class and change the inner HTML

$(".prev").each(function(i) {$(".prev")[i].innerHTML = "your icon"})